# SCP timeout delay?

Tags: timeout, raspberry-pi, scp

So im doing an scp from a raspberry pi to my computer, which is set to wake for internet requests, but it takes time to wake, Ive tested this by sshing into my computer from my phone, while my computer was closed, and it took a while (5-10 seconds) but worked. The problem is the pi scp requests time out before the comptuer wakes. The scp is run in a .sh script triggered by cron. How to I change the timeout time for scp? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ConnectTimeout` option:

```
scp -o ConnectTimeout=20 /myfile.txt user@host:/myfile.txt
```

If that still doesn't work, try using `ConnectionAttempts=2` (or higher) option, which will retry if the first one times out.